# TryCatch exception handling in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a function which take input and return as per the logic , I am new to trycatch and not able to get the respective results which I want, I would appreciate if someone could help

1. if the **library SHAPforxgboost** is not present , I want to stop the function and return an exception which states please install the library
2. I have to **check the input of the function** , if it's not dataframe or matrix stop the function and return an exception/ error stating that wrong input please enter data frame or matrix as input only.

**Also if possible is there any better way to check the input , it seems like a clumsy way of checking if dataframe or matrix present or not as per my logic**

```
example<-function(a){
  
  library("SHAPforxgboost")    ### Throw an custom error that library is not present please install                            
                               ### the  library and stop the function and return the error as o/p
   
                              ### Similarly if the input is not dataframe or matrix, stop the function 
                              ### and return custom error wrong input
  if("data.frame"==class(a)){
      print("correct input")
  }else if("matrix"==class(a)){
    print("correct input")
  } else{print("wrong input")}  
  return(x)
}
e<-as.vector(3)
s<-as.data.frame(4)
p<-as.matrix(2)
example(e)
example(s)
example(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for condition and `stop` the execution if the condition is not satisfied.

```
example<-function(a){

  if(!'SHAPforxgboost' %in% rownames(installed.packages()))
    stop('Please install SHAPforxgboost library')
  if(!(is.data.frame(a) | is.matrix(a)))
    stop('data should be either dataframe or matrix')
  #Do something
  #Do something
  #Return something
  return(x)
}
```

Comment: @ Ronakshah  can we achieve the same using trycatch

Comment: Yes, maybe. Although I don't think this would be the correct use of `tryCatch`. `tryCatch` is useful to handle warnings or errors in the code. `library('SHAPforxgboost')` would generate an error if it is not installed so that part can be covered using `tryCatch` but to check if the data is dataframe or matrix will not generate a warning or error.

Comment: You should use `stopifnot` for this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simple example helps:

```
divide = function(a,b)
      if(a/b)
        a/b

tryCatch({divide(10,'k')},
         error = function(e)
           {
           print("error in division")
         },
         finally = {
           print("in finally")
         })
```